# Creating count based upon counts of Group By Statement in LINQ / lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

What I want to do is group a huge bunch of records together by `Employer`. Then, I want to return an integer variable which will have a count of only those groups with at least `30` records.

I.E. I have `100` subscribers at `Employer A`, `20` at `Employer B`, and `30` at `Employer C`.

I group the records together and come up with

```
Employer A - 100
Employer B - 20
Employer C - 30
```

I want to return the Scalar Variable of `2`.

Here is what I currently have:

```
var Step1 =
    (from y in recordsActivstJoin
     where y.q.Market.Contains(market) && y.x.ActivistCodeID.Equals(activismCode)
     select new {y}).ToList();

            //this groups my previous query
var Step2 = (from z in Step1 group z by z.y.q.Employer into f select new {f}).ToList();
```

When I watch the locals I can see that it does in fact group down from Step 1 where there are 34 rows to 17 in step 2. Now, I want narrow to only those where the group is >=30 .

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not the best at writing LINQ blindly, but I'm fairly certain you are looking for something very close to the following:

```
var Step1 =
                (from y in recordsActivstJoin
                 where y.q.Market.Contains(market) && y.x.ActivistCodeID.Equals(activismCode)
                 select new {y}).ToList();

                        //this groups my previous query
var Step2 = (from i in Step1 group i by i.y.q.Employer into groupedEmployees
select new 
{
    EmployeeCount = groupedEmployees.Count()
}).Where(n=>n.EmployeeCount >= 30).Count();
```

Patrick pointed out that this could be shortened to:

```
var Step2 = Step1.GroupBy(i => i.y.q.Employer).Count(g => g.Count() >= 30);
```

`Step2` should be `2` in your example. Hope this helps!

Comment: Could shorten it a little bit:  `var Step2 = Step1.GroupBy(i => i.y.q.Employer).Count(g => g.Count() > 20);`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative:

- Query to group records by employer:

Code:

```
var groupedRecords = recordsActivstJoin
                     .Where(y => y.q.Market.Contains(market) && y.x.ActivistCodeID.Equals(activismCode))
                     .ToLookup(y => y.q.Employer);
```

- Count of the groups with more than 30 entries:

Code:

```
Int32 count = groupedRecords.Count(g => g.Count() >= 30);
```

Notes:

ToLookup is used at is most likely avalanche-safe compared to GroupBy which is typically not. It depends on the provider used to query your data e.g. There is no difference on LinqToObject whilst for LinqToSql there is a massive difference on big varied data sets.

ToLookup is immediate execution though, so if you want to deffer execution for the grouping you will need to go down a different path.